# Setting train array dimensions for face recognition for python

Tags: python, r, image-processing, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to find an equivalent code for python to set the following dimensions that I set in R:

```
dim(train_array) = c(28, 28, 1, ncol(train_x))
```

train_x is a matrix of 28 by 28 resized (grey scale) olivetti face images digitized into 784 (28 * 28) pixel rows (each row is labeled pixel.1, pixel.2, and so on) and 15 columns.  Is there any python package that does the same function as dim() for R in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is pandas shape function. Just use

```
train_array.shape
```

if you want to get the shape of dataframe
or

```
train_array.reshape(28, 28, 1, len(train_x))
```

if you want to change the dataframe shape.

Comment: This worked! Thank you @dportman

Comment: Great! @Phillip1982 accept the answer then.